How to prevent infinite loop when redirecting using middleware in Next.js
I have a middleware in Next.js:
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const isUserLoggedIn = ...

  if (isUserLoggedIn) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/user', request.url));
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

Basically, if a user is logged in, redirects to the private route of the app (this is just a simple example).
The problem is that when redirecting, the middleware gets called again in the new page and redirects again and so forth (infinite loop).
I tried using rewrite instead of redirect but the url is not changing and generally I don't think this case requires this method.
Has anyone encountered this behaviour before? Can someone suggest a safe solution?

Simply check if the url already is the new one and then do not perform the redirect.
Like so:
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const isUserLoggedIn = ...

  if (isUserLoggedIn && !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/user')) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/user', request.url));
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

